# Newlines in shell script variable not being replaced properly

Tags: shell, unix, newline

**Situation:** Using a shell script (bash/ksh), there is a message that should be shown in the console log, and subsequently sent via email.

**Problem:** There are newline characters in the message.

Example below:

```
   ErrMsg="File names must be unique. Please correct and rerun.
Duplicate names are listed below:
File 1.txt
File 1.txt
File 2.txt
File 2.txt
File 2.txt"
   echo "${ErrMsg}"
   # OK. After showing the message in the console log, send an email
```

**Question:** How can these newline characters be translated into HTML line breaks for the email?

**Constraint:** We must use HTML email. Downstream processes (such as Microsoft Outlook) are too inconsistent for anything else to be of use. Simple text email is usually a good choice, but off the table for this situation.

To be clear, the newlines do *not* need to be completely removed, but HTML line breaks *must* be inserted wherever there is a newline character.

This question is being asked because I have already attempted to use several commands, such as `sed`, `tr`, and `awk` with varying degrees of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The following snippet will do the job:

```
ErrMsg=`echo "$ErrMsg"|awk 1 ORS='<br/>'`
```

Just make sure there are double quotes around the variable when using `echo`.

---

This turned out to be a tricky situation. Some notes of explanation are below.

#### Using `sed`

Turns out, `sed` reads through input line by line, which makes finding and replacing those newlines somewhat outside the norm. There were several clever tricks that appeared to work, but I felt they were far too complicated to apply appropriately to this rather simple situation.

#### Using `tr`

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252010/2657515) the `tr` command should work. Unfortunately, this only translates character by character. The two character strings are not the same length, and I am limited to translating the newline into a space or other single character.

For the following:

```
ErrMsg="Line 1
Line 2
"
ErrMsg=`echo $ErrMsg| tr '\n' 'BREAK'`

# You might expect:
# "Line 1BREAKLine 2BREAK"
# But instead you get:
# "Line 1BLine 2B"
echo "${ErrMsg}"
```

#### Using `awk`

Using `awk` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853319/2657515) initially appeared to work, but due to some other circumstances with `echo` there was a subtle problem. The solution is noted in [this forum](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/26010-newlines-shell-variables.html).

**You must have double-quotes around your variable, or echo will strip out all newlines.**
(Of course, `awk` will receive the characters with a newline at the end, because that's what `echo` does after it echos stuff.)

This snippet is good: *(line breaks in the middle are preserved and replaced correctly)*

```
ErrMsg=`echo "$ErrMsg"|awk 1 ORS='<br/>'`
```

This snipped is bad: *(newlines converted to spaces by `echo`, one line break at end)*

```
ErrMsg=`echo $ErrMsg|awk 1 ORS='<br/>'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your message in `HTML` using `<pre>`, something like

```
<pre>
${ErrMsg}
and more.
</pre>
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but unfortunately, MS Outlook 2013 does NOT automatically respect newlines in text wrapped in `<pre>` ... so message still needs real HTML line breaks somehow.